# Hide Console Window while using Process.StartInfo with diffent Username

Tags: c#, .net

I'm starting a Process using a special User, Domain and Password. Although I told C# to hide the console window it is shown.

Here my code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process.StartInfo.UserName = strUsername;
process.StartInfo.Domain = strDomain;
process.StartInfo.Password = secPassword;

process.StartInfo.FileName = "PsExec.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/accepteula -s \\" + strServername + @"program.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I could find some hints in another forum:

> If you call the Start(ProcessStartInfo) method with the
>   ProcessStartInfo..::.UserName and ProcessStartInfo..::.Password
>   properties set, the unmanaged CreateProcessWithLogonW function is
>   called, which starts the process in a new window even if the
>   CreateNoWindow property value is true or the WindowStyle property
>   value is Hidden.

Actually, I'm not really satisfied with this statement...

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it is not possible to hide this psexec console window using the Process Class.
It's not necessary to use psexec. I used the WMI stuff instead:

```
ConnectionOptions remoteConnectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
remoteConnectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
remoteConnectionOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
remoteConnectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
remoteConnectionOptions.Username = strDomain + @"\" + strUsername;
remoteConnectionOptions.SecurePassword = secPassword;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + strServername + @"\root\CIMV2", remoteConnectionOptions); ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");

ManagementClass classInstance = new ManagementClass(scope, p, null); object[] theProcessToRun = { "myExecutable.exe" };

classInstance.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
```

Answer (score 1):

As i know there are workaround on this issue. You can launch hidden cmd with your params. Something like this:

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", String.Format("/accepteula -s \\{0}program.exe", strServername));
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
 Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Does it completely not working, or maybe it doesn't help you hide console window?

Comment: It starts the process, but the command window is still shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
            using (Process LMUTIL = new Process())
            {
                string arg1 ="argument"
                LMUTIL.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
                LMUTIL.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1
                LMUTIL.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                LMUTIL.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                LMUTIL.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                LMUTIL.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                LMUTIL.OutputDataReceived += p_WriteData;
                LMUTIL.Start();
                LMUTIL.BeginOutputReadLine();
            }

    private void p_WriteData(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I lifted this straight out of a project that does what you need. Subscribe to the p_WriteData event to capture what would appear in the command window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But the command window is shown, either. `process.StartInfo.UserName = strUsername;
process.StartInfo.Domain = strDomain;
process.StartInfo.Password = secPassword;` is also used in my code...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were running PSexec as your executable. Have you tried running PSexec with user credentials inserted as arguments rather than properties of the Process? Or do you require different credentials to run it locally?

Comment: Hi, I need different credentials... But I will try **runas**, that shouls work...